# C++ Movie Seating

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, permutation

I have been going crazy these past few days trying to figure out this seating assignment problem and was wondering if someone could help me.

**Instructions say:**

Assume that a group of n students arrives together for class (or a movie) and that exactly n seats are available consectutively in 1 row. Given m preferences on seating, you are to determine how many wants the students can be seated to statisfy the preferences.

**Input**

The input will come form the keyboard ONLY. The input will consist of multiple test cases. Each test case begins with two integers 0 < n and 0 ≤ m where n is the number of students to be seated, and m is the number of preferences. For simplicity, assume the students are numbered from 0 to n - 1. Then of m lines follow, each describing a preference, where a line consists of three integers a, b, and c satisfying 0 ≤ a < b < n and 0 < |c| < n. If c is positive then teenagers a and b want to sit at most c seats apart. If c is negative, then a and b want to sit at least -c seats apart. The end of input is signaled by a line consisting of n = m = 0.

**Output**

The output for each test case is a single line containing the number of possible seating arrangements for the group that satisfy all of the input constraints.

**Sample Input**

3 1

0 1 -2

3 0

0 0

**Sample Output**

2

6

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;


struct Preference
{
int a;
int b;                     //Struct with three preferences
int c;
};


int main()
{
int a,b,c,students,numpref;
int count = 0;

vector<Preference> prefs;              //Vector with struct to store preferences
Preference case1;

cout<<"Enter number of students and preferences: ";
cin>>students>>numpref;          //Total Number of students and preferences are entered



for(int i = 0; i<=numpref; i++)
{
cin>>case1.a>>case1.b>>case1.c;
prefs.push_back(case1);                  //Stores preferences in vector
cout<<endl;
}

vector<int> v2(a);               //Second vector created to store list of students

sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

while(next_permutation(v2.begin(), v2.end()))  
                                  //Finds all permutations of student seating
{


}


system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

I know it incomplete but I am stuck mainly trying to figure out how to compare each line of preferences to the correct permutations and then count the result. I thought about taking the position of each element in the vector that the user put as input(for instance: 0,1 in the example) and checking to see if each permutation that was found had 0 and 1 at least 2 seats between them. But that just wouldn't work.

Comment: Why do you say it wouldn't work?  Too slow?

Comment: Well every time I tried coming up with an if statement to compare the distance between two variables within the vector, the result wouldn't turn out right.

Comment: Have you created a function that will give you the distance between two specific students?

Comment: I tried using the myvector.at() function to try and figure out the distance between two students, but couldn't get it to work right, so I assumed that was not a good solution.

For example:

I tried doing something like "if(v2.at(a) - v2.at(b) >= c)."

But that obviously will never return the correct answer.

Comment: You need the inverse of vector::at, you want a function that will return the index of a particular student instead of the student at a particular index.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That actually makes a lot more sense. I was thinking of then trying something like:

int pos = find(v2.begin(), v2.end(), a) - v2.begin();

int pos2 = find(v2.begin(), v2.end(), b) - v2.begin();

I assumed that returns the position of both values but when I try it with my code, it doesn't seem to want to work. Maybe i'll try something else.

Comment: Don't you need to fill vector 'v2' with some values other than zero? Maybe take a look at std::generate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should fix that as I need the vector 'v2' to be filled with all students. Then I need to figure out how to compare that to the preferences.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you thought can work,but very slow. And I found some error in your incomplete code.

```
for(int i = 0; i<=numpref; i++)
```

I think this should be

```
for(int i = 0; i<numpref; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any recommendations on how to compare preferences to the permutations? The problem i'm having is trying to figure that out to count each time all of the user's preferences match the permutations and then store that as a result in a counter.

Comment: @Stephen Frankie If efficiency is not your consideration,for every permutation,you can compute a matrix which a(i,j)=distance(i,j), and then you can enumerate every preference using this matrix. I think this is easy to write code.

Comment: Hmmm..Thank you for the recommendation. I'll try and work out some code. I'm a new programmer so many of these concepts are quite new to me as well.